# kotlin class icon in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

It seems that android studio is not recognizing my kotlin class. The icon near the class does not appear as shown below

[image]

Subsequetly i cannot call the class in createFragment java class

Answer (score 0):

Showing a different icon happens often for me when there are multiple class declarations in the file. Something like this (within one file):

```
data class A(
  var uuids: List<UUID>
)

data class B(
  var numbers: List<Int>,
)
```

But without the code not much more can be said.

Comment: So, to make my point clear, I don't think that's the issue with AS, although you can always invalidate cache and restart the IDE to make sure

Comment: Hence how i can call the class kanban in myFragment(createFragment class)